# Trying to add more axis marks in Base R with date/time format using lubridate()

Tags: r, axis, lubridate

I apologize if this is a messy question, but I don't know any better way to format it. I'm trying to get it so on the x-axis of my graph, all of the dates I have in my dataset are shown. Right now, it's just about half of them - I'll attach a picture of my graph. I would also like if there were more tick marks between each date. I used the lubridate() function to combine my date/time columns, so that's not an issue. I was wondering if there was a way to manipulate the axis tick marks even though these aren't typical numerical values. I'll attach my code below.

```
PS4T1$newdate <- with(PS4T1, as.POSIXct(paste(date, time), format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M"))
plot(average ~ newdate, data=PS4T1, type="b", col="blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, format date `as.POSIXct`, this is important for which `plot` method is called, apparently you already have done that.

```
dat <- transform(dat, date=as.POSIXct(date))
```

Then, subset on the `substr`ings where hours are e.g. `'00'`. Next plot without x-axis and build custom axis using `axis` and `mtext`.

```
st <- substr(dat$date, 12, 13) == '00'

plot(dat, type='b', col='blue', xaxt='n')
axis(1, dat$date[st], labels=F)
mtext(strftime(dat$date[st], '%b %d'), 1, 1, at=dat$date[st])
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(
  date=as.character(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct('2021-06-22'), as.POSIXct('2021-06-29'), 'hour')),
  v=runif(169)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it! I just have one issue - when I try to run this, it says mtext has a zero-length "text" specified. Could it be because my dates are formatted differently? In my csv file, I have the dates formatted as M-DD-YYYY and time formatted as HH:MM:SS.

Comment: @RachelDavitt Could you try `dat <- transform(dat, date=strptime(date,'%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'))` to reformat it?

Comment: I did, I'm still getting the same error message. It's definitely an error on my end that I can try and figure out or ask another question. I appreciate all of your help!!

Comment: @RachelDavitt Probably all `st` are `FALSE`. Which time values do you have in your data? I assumed there is always `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00` midnight available. Try `substr('98765', 3, 4)` to understand the logic.

Comment: I ended up fixing it - I was using "date" instead of "newdate" which had all NA values. It's plotted now just with minor visual issues. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @RachelDavitt So cool, thx for the feedback! :)